# How to multi-thread HTTP calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along the Stanford cs193p iOS course from iTunes and am really stuck on figuring out how to structure an assignment.

Let's say that I want to use `NSCoreData` to store a bunch of photos that are pulled from Flickr and want to be able to run queries based on the region where the photo was taken, so each photo will be a part of 1 region but a region can have many photos.

We use the Flickr API to get a list of all of the photos, but in order to get the photo region we need to make another request to the Flickr API to get the details for each photo. What is the best way to structure this?

The way that I'm doing it now is that I pull the list of photos from Flickr and loop through them, if any are not in the DB then I create a new entry. When I create a new photo entry then it uses a region class to get the region, but if the region doesn't exist then it has to make another HTTP request to the Flickr API to get the details, which takes time.

More generally, suppose that I was using an API to fetch a list of cars for sale from the Internet, and then to get the details of each car required making another request to the API, what would be the best way to structure this programmatically if I wanted to do it all at once?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the "extras:geo" argument to your API request, which would add the "accuracy" (region) to each photo in the response.